# DateTimeOffset [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using .NET 4.6.1 and EF6.1.3 code-first. I have a model with DateTimeOffset property annotated with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] that bumps into "Cannot insert the value NULL" error when SaveChanges is called. Anyone has the same problem out there?

Comment: make the DateTimeOffset property nullable

Comment: value types cannot be null by default.

Comment: DatabaseGenerated just tells EF that the DB is responsible to create the values. You still have to set a Default Value constraint for the column in the DB. Example for code first migrations: `AlterColumn("dbo.YourTable", "YourColumn", c => c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: 'YourDefaultExpression'));`